# Published ArcGIS Server domain views

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-enterprise

I have created an sde table in PostgreSQL 9.5 named `parcels` from ArcCatalog version 9.5.

```
ID   NAME  TYPE_ID
1    x     1
2    y     1
3    z     2
```

I created parcel types as Domain in ArcCatalog. So I can see my data in ArcMap like this:

```
ID   NAME  TYPE_ID
1    x     Type-1
2    y     Type-1
3    z     Type-2
```

So I will publish this table on ArcGIS Server Enterprise 10.5. How will users see my TYPE of parcels, when they get feature info. As numeric or domain description value?

Comment: I certainly hope you didn't create and publish this as an "sde table" (owned and accessed as the `sde` login). SDE, the product, no longer exists. Tables in in an enterprise geodatabase can be referred to as "tables" or "feature classes", but "sde table" creates unnecessary confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have assigned a domain to a field in a feature class, after you will have a map service published, the values visible to the end users will come from the domain. So, it will be `domain description value`.

Comment: Will I use domain code value while updating?

Comment: No, when editing the features you need to submit the "real" values (so if you have an integer field, you won't be able to pass a string). The domain won't handle this for you.